# Couldn't match expected type [a] with actual type Maybe[a]

Tags: haskell

please pardon for very beginner level quesion.

I am now trying to introduce Maybe into my previous helper function (which swaps the first two elements of the list) to enable empty list error handling:

...haskell

```
-- | the helper funtion to only swap the first two elements.
swap_first_two_elements :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swap_first_two_elements list = case list of
  x:y:xs -> Just (y:x:xs)
  _      -> Nothing
```

and invoking it in

```
 interprete s x

  | x `elem` ["+","-","*","/","^"] = operate x s
  | x `elem` ["inc","dec","sqrt","sin","cos","inv"] =  operate2 x s
  | x `elem` ["+all"] =  [sum s]
  | x `elem` ["dup"] =  (head s) :s
  | x `elem` ["pop"] =   tail s
  | x `elem` ["swap"] =    swap_first_two_elements s
  | x `elem` ["clear"] =  drop (length s) s
  | x `elem` ["*all"] =  [product s]
  | otherwise = read x:s
  where
    operate op (x:y:s) = case op of
      "+" -> x + y:s
      "-" -> y - x:s
      "*" -> x * y:s
      "/" -> y / x:s
      "^" -> y ** x:s
```

But I am getting an error like

```
  Couldn't match expected type [a] with actual type Maybe[a]
```

I read other related posts and modified it like:

```
  | x `elem` ["swap"] =   swap_first_two_elements Just(s)
```

Still got error. Could experts offer where I go wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Likely your `interprete s x` is supposed to return an `[a]`, not a `Maybe [a]`.

Comment: is that the entire `interprete` function? It looks like you gave it a return type of the form `[a]` rather than `Maybe [a]`, but without more context it's not clear what the "best" way to fix the problem is.

Comment: Note that ``x `elem` ["swap"]`` is equivalent to `x == "swap"`.

Comment: The error is not the input type of `swap_first_two_elements`, but the *output* type, it is (likely) not compatible with the output type of `interprete`.

Comment: ``drop (length s) s == drop 1 (take 1 $ undefined : s) == [] `asTypeOf` s``.

Answer (score 3):

So you have

```
interprete s x
  | x `elem` ["pop"]  =   tail s
  | x `elem` ["swap"] =   swap_first_two_elements s
```

Now,

```
tail                    :: [a] ->       [a]
```

but

```
swap_first_two_elements :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

and of course those are two different types altogether.

You can't return a value of one type in some case, and of another type altogether in some other cases. All cases in a function definition must return values of the *same* type.

A function goes from a type to a *type*, not to *types*.

You can fix your definition by wrapping all the other cases' values in a `Just`, like so:

```
  | x `elem` ["pop"]  =   Just (tail s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for your code to have more sense, I think you need to spread the Maybe all over the sub-functions, for example in operate, and pop and all other "unsafe" functions, you can take advantage of Maybe type, like divide by 0:

```
interprete s x
                | x `elem` ["+","-","*","/","^"] = operate x s
                | x `elem` ["inc","dec","sqrt","sin","cos","inv"] = Just (operate2 x s)
                | x `elem` ["+all"] =  Just([sum s])
                | x `elem` ["dup"] = dup s
                | x `elem` ["pop"] = pop s 
                | x `elem` ["swap"] = swap_first_two_elements s
                | x `elem` ["clear"] = Just []
                | x `elem` ["*all"] = Just([product s])
                | otherwise = Just(read x:s)

pop [] = Nothing
pop (x:xs) = Just xs

dup [] = Nothing
dup s@(x:xs) = Just (x:s) 

operate op (x:y:s) = case op of
  "+" -> Just(x + y:s)
  "-" -> Just(y - x:s)
  "*" -> Just( x * y:s)
  "/" -> case x of 
        0  -> Nothing
        n  -> Just(y / x:s)
  "^" -> Just(y ** x:s)
operate _ _ = Nothing

swap_first_two_elements :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
swap_first_two_elements (x:y:xs)  = Just (y:x:xs)
swap_first_two_elements _ = Nothing

operate2 = undefined
```

I don't know what operate2 does, so, I leave it to you. But by sure, it has type [a] -> Maybe [a], so please, make it return a Maybe [a], please.